# ios programming - Data argument not used by format string

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

I get a `Data argument not used by format string` error when I run the following code:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSString *colour = ([colourArray objectAtIndex:row]);

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:(colour) forKey:@"colour"];

NSLog(@"NSString =", colour);
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults =", [defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]);

}
```

I get the error on both `NSLog` lines. Also, here is what the log says:

```
2011-10-25 09:01:50.260 Random[35636:b303] NSString =
2011-10-25 09:01:50.260 Random[35636:b303] NSUserDefaults =
```

Thank you,
Arthur

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"NSString = ", colour);    
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults =", [defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]);
```

Is problematic

Should be

```
NSLog(@"NSString = %@", colour);
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults = %@", [defaults objectForKey:@"colour"]);
```

The format specifier in this case is the `%@` which is used to print an `object`. To print numbers you'd use something like `%d`. [See complete documentation here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @debuggerman is absolutely correct. But you can improve your code if you use `[defaults setObject:colour forKey:@"colour”];` instead of `[defaults setObject:(colour) forKey:@"colour"];`

Note that I removed the parentheses for object `colour`.